# Why isn't this calendar working?

Tags: html, css

I wrote this code for calendar and it's working on one file and not on the other. Have a look:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
           <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
        });
        </script>
        <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Why isn't it working on just one file?

Comment: It's working fine. Please check your console it's given any error.

Comment: It is saying that datepicker() is not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is another library that is using the $ variable, you can do this:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(function() {
        $j( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste this:

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">     
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>

</head>

 <body>    
   <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>          
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this works for me! try copy paste my code to a new file.

Comment: yes. it is saying that 'datepicker' is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your link to JQuery-UI is invalid, fix that and it will work.

https://jsfiddle.net/jamiguel77/atg5m6ym/

```
//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js
```

Comment: Are you saying that I should replace `code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js` by `https://jsfiddle.net/jamiguel77/atg5m6ym/` ?

Comment: no, the correct jquery-ui link is //code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js.  The jsfiddle shows a working example.  I try to reference your jquery-ui in there and was not able to find it.

Comment: replace this line of yours "  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>" with this "      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>"